# yet another "toggle visibility" question

Tags: javascript, jquery, visibility

I am stuck with the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/2v4aJ/

I want to toggle some text using hidden/visible.

I am using javascript functions to add dynamic text to the page, that's why I use .live ...

I can toggle to hide, but not to visible (if($('#1').is(':hidden')) is never true).

Any help appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the [jQuery docs on :hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/),

> Elements with visibility: hidden are considered to be visible, since they still consume space in the layout

so you'd better check for the value.

```
if ($('#1').css('visibility')==='hidden')
```

or use other method

Comment: ah thanks! I figured out that the space in the layout is still consumed but did not think to check the value! I'm going to try that out later and accept!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) pseudo-selector treats elements with `visibility:hidden` as visible, because they still take up space on the page. From the jQuery docs:

> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered to be
>   visible, since they still consume space in the layout.

Instead, you can check the value of the CSS property itself:

```
if($('#1').css("visibility") === "hidden") {
    $('#1').css('visibility','visible');
}
else {
    $('#1').css('visibility','hidden');
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I accepted Einacio's answer since he was first and can't upvote you since this account is new, but maybe someone else will!

Answer (score 0):

First of all `:hidden` selector is not for you:

> *Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered to be visible, since they still consume space in the layout.*

You can use `:visible` selector, but it works only when element invisible and `display:none`. In your case you need to check css property:

Also, pleae note that `visibility:hidden` reserves space for element, `display:none` - not;

If you don't need to reserve space for it I suggest to use:

```
        $('#text').click(function() {
            $('#2').toggle();
        });
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/2v4aJ/6/

Comment: `:hidden` also checks true for elements with height-width:0 or display:none

Comment: reserving space with :hidden was intentional for my application, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use the [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) command.

```
$('#1').toggle(true); //show
$('#1').toggle(false); //hide
$('#1').toggle(); //flip
```

Comment: toggle changes the `display` property. RegexCommander is working with visibility